# removing Class from array using Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the classname "activeTab" from All the elements in var items.

However i get a error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

this is my current Javascript as its stands now:

```
/**
 * Tabs Logic
 */
 function displayPage() {
   var items = navitem.querySelectorAll(".configurator-menuitems div");
   removeClass(items, "activeTab");
   this.className += " " + "activeTab";
 }

function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return !!ele.classList.match(new RegExp("(\\s|^)"+cls+"(\\s|$)"));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp("(\\s|^)"+cls+"(\\s|$)");
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg," ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) functions? `items.forEach(function(el){el.classList.remove("activeTab")})` and `this.classList.add("activeTab")` should do the same thing as those last two lines in `displayPage`.

Comment: I tried but getting the name error. Also items.forEach is not a function error?

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array. Essentially, you want to loop over all of the matches for your selector `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {items[i].classList.remove("activeTab");}` should actually work.

Comment: So i didnt know about NodeList but also the items are not being removed they are just adding on per click. sorry its confused me haha

Comment: turns out i was using the wrong selector thanks mate :)

Comment: My notes say .classList is only supported IE 10 and later and has a .contains() method to test for class. My older hasClass method just does an indexOf test against ele.className